# How to view the topic of the mosquitto broker subscription

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm writing a python project which need to send message by mqtt. I find a problem that when I send a order which need subscriber to download a big file which need to spend few minutes, whereagfter subscriber called on_connect func again, at the moment the subscriber cannot receive any message it subscribed. this bug happens occasionally.

After many test, I find that ss long as the on_connect function is called after downloading a large file, the subscriber  cannot receive other messages.
And subscriber can send a message stating that mqtt has no problem, can also receive after opening a terminal subscription message.

So, I guess the subscription was disconnected after downloading the large file. I need to check the topic of the broker's internal connection subscription to verify my guess.

But I don't konw how to check it. Please tell me the method to inspect broker and how to fix this question if the guess is proved correct

Because there's too much code, I'm going to outline it

```
cloud send a series of order including download file, modified and the likes by mqtt
```

```
devices receive message by mqtt, then operate order and feedback
```

After devices download big file, there is a probability that other MQTT messages cannot be received when terminal print the result that `wait handle : Connected with result code 0` of on_connect func which is type

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("wait handle : Connected with result code " + str(rc))
```

Comment: Are you sending the big file via MQTT? While is is possible to do so, the purpose of the protocol is an other one. It is not designed to transport large amounts of data but small amounts over connections that are not guaranteed to be reliable or fast.

Comment: No, MQTT only send operating instructions and data within few M. I set qos equal to 2, so it should be reliable, but the subscriberhasn't received a follow-up message after downloading file and printing the result of on_connect func

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you are doing long running tasks in either the `on_connect` or `on_message` callbacks.

These callbacks run on the MQTT client's network thread, this thread is used to handle the sending and receiving of network packets. If it blocks for too long then the keep alive (time between MQTT packets) will expire and the broker will disconnect the client.

If you have long running tasks they need to be run on a separate thread.

Using `subprocess` and waiting for it to finish so you can get the output then you are blocking for the length of time the process takes to run, so you might as well be running it on the same thread.